# Moving context into several closures?

Tags: rust

I have found a way to move context into several closures, but it looks ugly. I do it with help of `Rc` and cloning each variable I need to use for each closure. Particularly I don't like to clone every variable for every closure I want to use:

```rust
  let mut context = Rc::new( Context { a : 13 } );
  ..

  let context_clone_1 = Rc::clone( &context );
  engine.on_event1( Box::new( move ||
  { 
    println!( "on_event1 : {}", context_clone_1.a );
    ...

  let context_clone_2 = Rc::clone( &context );
  engine.on_event2( Box::new( move ||
  {
    println!( "on_event1 : {}", context_clone_1.a );
    ...
```

It is an extensive way to go and I feel there must be a better way to do it. Also, uncommenting line `// context_clone_1.a += 1;` breaks the compilation. What is the proper way of solving problems like this in Rust?

Here is a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=438a24c222f654c8308dabdb21dbd4c7) with minimal code.

Comment: Uncommenting the line breaks the compilation, because it's illegal to modify an immutable structure. Also there is nothing wrong with using `Rc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two "problems" here:

Since you specifically asked about `context_clone_1.a += 1;`: When putting a value into an `Rc`, there could be multiple references to that value, derived from the independent `Rc` owners. If mutation was allowed, this would also allow simultaneous mutation and aliasing, which is not allowed in Rust; therefore `Rc` does not allow mutating its inner value. A common approach to regain mutability is to put the value into a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which provides mutability through [`try_borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.try_borrow_mut) with a runtime check that ensures no aliasing occurs. A `Rc<RefCell<T>>` is commonly seen in Rust.

Regarding the use of `Rc`: The way your code is currently set up is actually fine, at least if that's how it should work. The way the code is currently structured allows for flexibility, including cases where multiple Context-objects provide callback implementations on different events. For example, this is currently possible:

```
let context1 = Context { a : 13 };
engine.on_event1(Box::new(move ||
{ 
  println!("on_event1 : {}", context1.a );
});

let context2 = Context { a : 999 };
engine.on_event2(Box::new(move ||
{
  println!("on_event1 : {}", context2.a );
});
```

In case you have exactly one Context (as in your example), and since the `Engine` needs to make *sure* that all callbacks are alive while it itself is alive, you'll need to put each callback - which is structured as a completely separate thing - into a `Rc`. In your case, all `Rc` end up pointing to the same object; but they don't have to and this is what your code currently allows for.

A more simple solution would be to define a trait for `Context`, something along the lines of

```
trait EventDriver {
    fn event1(&mut self, &Engine);
    fn event2(&mut self, &Engine);
}
```

... and then have `Context` implement the trait. The `Engine`-struct then becomes generic over `E: EventDriver` and `Context` becomes the `E` in that. This solution only allows for exactly one instance of `Context` to provide event callbacks. But since `Engine` is the owner of that object, it can be sure that all callbacks are alive while it itself is alive and the whole `Rc`-thing goes away.